# Confusion matrix from probabilities

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I have the following scikit-learn machine learning pipeline:

```
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                     random_state=random_state)

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

i = 0
for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    i += 1
```

Now I would like to also calculate (and plot) the confusion matrix. How can this be done with the above code? I'm only getting probabilities (which I need for caluclating AUC). I have 4 classes (1...4).

Comment: Well you have the probabilities of the predicted labels and the original labels so why don't you go ahead and use that with `sklearn.confusion_matrix`?

Comment: Why not just use predict(X[test]) for confusion matrix.

Comment: @VivekKumar If I'm using also random search for hyperparameter optimization, then using both predict_proba and predict would lead to a computational overhead because random search uses cross-validation. So I would have a random search for predict_proba and predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example here to plot confusion matrix:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py

But for this, you need to have discrete class values (not probabilities). Which can be easily derived from your `probas_` variable using:

```
y_pred = np.argmax(probas_, axis=1)
```

Now you can use this y_pred in confusion matrix

Comment: Thank you very much. But I want to compute the confusion matrix after the for-loop, i.e. on all data points (not a subset). How can I keep track of it? I mean in each loop iteration I have the predictions for test and I have to store it somehow in a variable y_total at the correct positions matching y so that I can call confusion_matrix(y_total, y) in the end.

Comment: @machinery So will you again calculate predict_probas for all data points after the loop?

Comment: No, I will not calculate it again. In the loop I calculate the probabilities for all the data points. The problem is that I have the array y and in each loop iteration I calculate only a part of y_pred. So I have to stich the array together to get the final prediction.

Comment: @machinery But do you understand that the final array is not the uniform prediction, but dependent on different parts of training data

Comment: Yes but what should I do otherwise? I cannot average the confusion matrix over the loop. Moreover,